# Python Packages not installing on Mac

Tags: python, pip

I am on a MacBook Air 13' on Catalina and use PyCharm for coding with python 3.8.3. I have beed trying to use pip 21.1.3 to install packages into projects, but, this keeps coming up:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/audioplayer/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/audioplayer/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement audioplayer (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for audioplayer
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
```

I don't know what it means or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is looks like a networking error, try adding:

```
pip3 install  --trusted-host pypi.org <your package>
```

Probably you have something blocking the access